# SSRS grouping by aging

Tags: reporting-services

I created a report with multiple fields and I have a field named Ageddays that calculated the aging days on each row of data. I need to group by Ageddays <31, <61, <91, and <121. The report should look like this below and any helps is appreciated.

```
Header    ClientName   Item    Purdate  Ageddays  Location  Salesperson  Paid
Group by**Ageddays < 31**
Detail     XYX LLC       toy1  12/21/2017  10      ABC address   Sam        No
           AAA LLC       toy2  11/11/2017  20      ABC address   Sam        No
           **Ageddays < 61**
           CDF LLC       toy3  08/21/2017  40      EEB address   Rey        No
           AAA co.       toy4  07/11/2017  50      YYY address   Sam        No
           **Ageddays < 91**
           MMY Co.       toy3  06/21/2017  60      EEB address   Eri        No
           GGG Co.       toy4  05/11/2017  70      YYY address   Abe        No
```

Comment: Good luck. what do you want from us?

Comment: Ideally, you should assign the grouping to the resulting data at SQL end and then use that field for grouping in SSRS.

Comment: You could also create a computed column based on the `Ageddays` ranges (all records in the same range get the same value in the computed column), and then group on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional column based on the condition you want. I mean the new column value should be

```
Case when agedays<31 then 1
When agedays<61 then 2
When agedays<91 then 3
 When agedays<121 then 4
 Else 4 end as groupcategory.
```

Then you can group the data using this groupcategory field.

Comment: Thanks. On my SQL I did a case statement when agedays < 31 then '<31'

Comment: Thanks. On my SQL I did a case statement when agedays < 31 then '<31'  when agedays between 31 and  60 then '<61'   when agedays between 61 and 90 then '<91' end as 'Sort by period'.  On SSRS group by rows pane below I added a Parent group and chose  'Sort by period' . on the  tablix report  detail row I added a row group by above and chose adjacent  above. That resolves by problem. Thanks for all the suggestions and I was able to combine it.